# Converting javascript time with php Carbon returns strange time?

Tags: time, timezone, php-carbon

I'm setting my time using javascript when creating/updating my cookie.

```
// get current time
let d = new Date();
let time = d.getTime();
```

Which variable `time` becomes this string...

```
1586186947954
```

The number above should result `16:29 GMT 6 April 2020`

But when I run this number with [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/)...

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$updated = Carbon::parse($cart['updated']['time']);
```

This is returned...

```
Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 52234-04-07 05:32:34.000000
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +00:00
)
```

Which is way off for reason. Minutes and the date are no where near.

I'm trying to output this timestamp in the timezone `Asia/Dubai` too if I can get Carbon to return the right time anyway.

Any ideas would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parse` method is for parsing more complex strings, so it is misinterpreting the value you're passing.

You should instead construct the object like this:

```
Carbon::createFromTimestampMs(1586186947954, 'Asia/Dubai')
```

Comment: Yes, April lol. This is absolutely perfect man thanks for steering me in the right direction.